# Some doubts regarding consistency of an axiomatic system

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

So these are mostly doubts I have, but:

1. What's the difference (if any) between the meta statement "ZFC is consistent" and the formal statement Con(ZFC) expressed in ZFC? I've heard that they're different, but how? Con(ZFC) cannot be proven in ZFC, is there any way either Con(ZFC) or "ZFC is consistent" can be proven, perhaps in another axiomatic system? And if not, what's the difference between the two?
2. Can a statement be true but unprovable? What does it mean to say a statement is true if it is unprovable?
3. Is it possible to prove within ZFC the equivalence of a statement X and Con(ZFC)?
4. What does it mean for Con(ZFC) to be false? Can there exist a proof in ZFC that Con(ZFC) is false?
5. If Con(ZFC) is false, does it also simultaneously become true? In general if a system of axioms is inconsistent, doesn't it mean that every statement expressible in that system can be proven both true and false?
6. Is the set of statements equivalent to Con(ZFC) a strict subset of the set of statements independent of ZFC? Does the notion of statements independent of ZFC exist if ZFC is inconsistent?

Any reading material that you would recommend to understand this topic better?

Comment: There are a lot of questions on the site that answer part of your 6 questions, if not all of them.

Comment: In general, for every axiomatic system we may ask if it is consistent or not; it is not obvious that we can "express" this fact **about** a system $T$ **inside** $T$ itself.

Comment: Under some *specific* condition, a formal system $T$ can "express" facts about itself.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA What does it mean to ask if it is consistent or not? What axiomatic system are we assuming to ask this question? Or are we allowed to such a question without assuming an axiomatic system?

Comment: @AsafKaragila With all due respect that's just SE being unhelpful. Am I supposed to ask on chat as per the "rules"? If everyone could go search answers to their own doubts, no one would have doubts

Comment: There are different (but equivalent) definition of *consistency* of an axiom system; basically, $T$ is **in**-consistent iff there is a formula $A$ such that $T$ proves both $A$ and $\lnot A$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Okay so there exist multiple equivalent definitions of Con(ZFC). Are these all formal and can we prove them equivalent within ZFC?

Comment: No, that's you writing 6 questions which are arguably separate questions, instead of putting some effort to find out some answers yourself *on this site*. This is the platform's point. Not for you to ask, but for you to find answers.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Okay I'll spend some more time searching. I get it's not your fault, it's SE policy. I just wish we had a forum that was willing to let people who wanna help/spoon-feed just do so, SE seems to not allow for this

Comment: About 2: according to G's original point of view (the "platonist", or "realist" one) statements of *arithmetic* are about *numbers*. G's Inc Th proves that there is a sentence $G$ of *formal* first-order Peano arithmetic ($\mathsf {PA}$) such that neither $\mathsf {PA} \vdash G$ nor $\mathsf {PA} \vdash \lnot G$. But both $G$ and $\lnot G$ are *sentences* of arithmetic, i.e. are sentences expressing facts about number, which means that **one** of them **must** be true in $\mathbb N$. That's all...

Comment: About 5: if $\mathsf {ZFC}$ is **inconsistent**, then yes, it proves all and thus also $\text {Cons}(\mathsf{ZFC})$ and $\lnot \text {Cons}(\mathsf{ZFC})$. Again, only one of them will be true: the one corresponding to "facts" i.e. $\lnot \text {Cons}(\mathsf{ZFC})$. But the theory proves also $\text {Cons}(\mathsf{ZFC})$ which is false: this is consequence of inconsistency: an incons theory is not *sound*, i.e. it proves false sentences.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks. What does corresponding to "facts" mean - isn't that simply a reference to another axiomatic system? Within ZFC, Cons(ZFC) is either {true} or {both true and false}, and it's provably undecidable which of these is right. Are you saying there could still exist another axiomatic system where Cons(ZFC) is still strictly true or strictly false, one that will remain sound even if ZFC is unsound?